# Can I update a Cisco RV320 v03 to v04?

Tags: cisco, firmware

I bought a Cisco RV320 dual-WAN Gigabit VPN router that keeps freezing after about 12 hours or so of use. On the System Summary page, it shows that it is a RV320-K9 v03, firmware version 1.3.2.02. I have several other Cisco RV320s that work perfectly. They are RV320-K09 v04, firmware version 1.3.1.12. I downloaded and attempted to apply the 1.3.1.12 firmware to the V03 router, but after the reboot, it still showed v03, 1.3.2.02.

There are a plethora of RV320 firmware options at
https://software.cisco.com/download/home/284005929/type/282465789/release/1.5.1.13

As far as I can tell, none of them specify whether they are for v03, v04, or what. I don't know whether the 1.3.1.12 firmware failed on the v03 because that version only works on v04, or because it's an older version. I am averse to blindly downloading other firmware versions and would rather see if someone has some specific knowledge about this.

Comment: You are aware that you're trying to downgrade your 'new' router? And that the last firmware rev is the 1.5.1.13 you linked to? And you cannot upgrade hardware revisions.

Comment: I am trying to turn a non-working router into a working one. Is 1.5.1.13 for the V03? If not, which versions are? How would one tell?

Comment: IF the release notes don't specify a required/compatible hardware revision, then you can probably run whichever firmware you want. 

For the most reliable upgrade process, I recommend updating to the latest release in the major release train you have currently installed. In this case, install 1.3.2.02 and then try to go to the next major release supported on the model (1.4.2.22 and then to 1.5.1.13, step by step). 

I don't see any information on the documents indicating that kind of upgrade process is required but it is usually safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I update a Cisco RV320 v03 to v04?

Those are hardware revisions that you cannot update.

Generally, you should aim for the latest release as it usually fixes the most issues. Make sure you've read the release notes to note the required (intermediate) steps and to ensure proper configuration migration (you should always have a backup also).

Hardware revisions are only relevant if they are explicitly mentioned in the release notes. That doesn't seem to be the case here.

What you describe is a downgrade from a later release to an earlier release. Downgrades should not be done without good reasons and may require additional steps.

You should note that the RV320 [reached end of software maintenance in January 2021](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/small-business-rv-series-routers/eos-eol-notice-c51-743069.html), so the mentioned 1.5.1.13 is most likely the final software release and further problems remain unfixed. You might want to look for a newer model.

Answer (score -1):

The best thing is to downgrade it to the original version via ftp and then once it is in its original state, it is added to the version one by one until it reaches the latest one, thus correcting any errors that are occurring.

Comment: Your answer would be a good fit for a question where the firmware upgrade path wasn't followed, but the OP's question is about *hardware* revisions.